# Best way to alter user input in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

What i've got currently is a textarea that takes in a comma separated string of words that i want to serialize as an array in the DB.

I've got a model that serializes an array

```
class Ipsum < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :words, Array
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Currently in my controller, I take the user input from the text area and convert the type from string to array doing the following.

```
class IpsumsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    params[:ipsum][:words] = params[:ipsum][:words].split(',')
    @ipsum = Ipsum.new(ipsum_params)

    if @ipsum.save
      redirect_to @ipsum
    end
  end

  private

    def ipsum_params
      params.require(:ipsum).permit(:title, :author, :words)
    end
end
```

This works as expected, but i'm wondering is there's a better way to do this, ie some kind of before_serialization callback, or some kind of form serialization.

Here's the form currently as well, im using ruby-slim.

```
= form_for(@ipsum) do |f|
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title

  = f.label :words
  = f.text_area :words, value: ''

  = f.submit 'Submit'
```

Comment: if you are looking for validation along with alert only client side then go for http://jqueryvalidation.org/ .so you can customise it the way you need with excellent callbacks without handling major server validations

Answer (score 1):

In your model you could use:

```
before_save :split_words

def split_words
  self.words = words.split ','
end
```

And delete from controller:

```
params[:ipsum][:words] = params[:ipsum][:words].split(',')
```

Comment: Thanks, logic helper me to figure out how to go about changing input in models, not in the controller